Applying Pressure in z-direction in quantum espresso
I am working with Bilayer 2H-MoS2, interlayer spacing ~3A. I want to apply pressure in z-direction which can lead to reduction in interlayer spacing, and then calculating its electronic properties. so, How to induce this pressure?
Thanks

Do you consider just pressure in z-direction and want to leave x and y fixed or do you want to model relaxation in x- and y-direction in the spirit of Poisson's ratio?
